# Как отправить запрос к *.php фалу

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Допустим у меня есть компонент регистрации register.vue. Компонент на стороне клиента должен проверить инпуты и отправить эти данные в php файл(допустим reg.php), что бы внести пользователя в БД. Как это сделать методами Vue.js?

И так же похожий вопрос. Как получить данные в *.vue файл из БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, в vue нету стандартного метода для запросов к серверу. Можно использовать xmlhttprequest, можно fetch или библиотеки. Одна из самых распространенных - axios, но есть и другие альтернативы.

Для axios пример будет как то так: `axios.post('http://example.com', {param: 1})` .

Еще очень важно то, что в axios можно задать базовый адрес для запросов, а дальше использовать относительны адреса, очень упрощает работу.

Документация: https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api .